# How can I combine these two queries into a single query but have each query's output in separate columns

Tags: sqlite

Can I run these two queries  in a single query and have the resulting data from each one stored in separate columns.

```
select stars as Med
from business
where city = "Pittsburgh" and is_open = 1 and stars between 2 and 3

select stars as High
from business
where city = "Pittsburgh" and is_open = 1 and stars between 4 and 5
```

I tried:

```
select stars as Med
from business
where city = "Pittsburgh" and is_open = 1 and stars between 2 and 3
Union
select stars as High
from business
where city = "Pittsburgh" and is_open = 1 and stars between 4 and 5
```

But I only got column "Med" back

```
+-----+
| med |
+-----+
| 2.0 |
| 2.5 |
| 3.0 |
| 4.0 |
| 4.5 |
| 5.0 |
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

AS you have found UNION extends/appends additional rows. If you want additional columns then your include them as columns to be output.

However, doing the latter, without some criteria for pairing the med and the high then the other column needs to have some value e.g. null.

Without any such criteria you could satisfy your question by using:-

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN stars >= 2.0 AND stars <= 3 THEN stars ELSE null END AS med, 
    CASE WHEN stars > 3.0 AND stars <= 5.0 THEN stars ELSE null END AS high 
FROM business WHERE is_open = 1 AND city = 'Pittsburgh' AND stars between 2 AND 5
;
```

Which would result in *(based upon the result shown)*:-

[image]